# Optimizing Tomcat / Garbage Collection

Tags: java, tomcat, optimization, garbage-collection, performance

Our server has 128GB of RAM and 64 cores, running Tomcat 7.0.30 and Oracle jdk1.6.0_38, on CentOS 6.3.

Every 60 minutes we're seeing garbage collection that was taking 45 - 60 seconds.  Adding -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC increased page load times by about 10% but got that down to about 3 seconds, which is an acceptable trade-off.

Our config:

```
-Xms30g
-Xmx30g
-XX:PermSize=8g
-XX:MaxPermSize=8g
-Xss256k
-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

We set the heap at 30 GB to keep 32 bit addressing (I read that above 32 GB the 64 bit addressing takes up more memory, so you have to go to about 48 GB to see improvements).

Using VisualGC I can see that the Eden space is cycling through every 30 - 60 minutes, but not much happens with the Survivor 0, Survivor 1, Old Gen, and Perm Gen.

We have a powerful server.  What other optimizations can we make to further decrease the 3 second GC time?

Any recommendations to improve performance or scaling?

Any other output or config info that would help?

Comment: `-XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC` isn't this off by default, perhaps you meant to turn it on with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` This will make no difference to the eden size in any case.

Comment: find where you create so many object and see where you can optimize it out with pools and/or caching

Comment: If you see little activity on the old gen, why are you getting full GCs.  I suspect it is being triggered when you don't need it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're right, that was supposed to be a + sign.  I made the switch, and the page load times increased by 50%.  I haven't seen how long GC takes yet. The other improvements must have been from our switch from OpenJDK to the Oracle JDK, and from 36GB heap to 30GB heap.

Comment: The HotSpot documentation is a bit confusing unless you read the small print.  The options don't show you how to turn options on, they tell you what the default option is. i.e. if you use them as quoted they shouldn't do anything. ;)

Comment: This seems to be the winning combination so far:  `-XX:GCTimeRatio=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=2000
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`

Comment: You could also use `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` or `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses` which plugs the explicit GCs on CMS instead of a full GC, instead of completely disabling them.

Answer (score 4):

It might sound counter-intuitive, but have you tried allocating a lot less memory? E.g. do you really need a 30G heap? In case you can get along with 4G or even less: Garbage collection might be more frequent, but when it happens it will be a lot faster. Typically I find this more desirable than allocating a lot of memory, suffering from the time it takes to clean it up.

Even if this will not help you because *you* really need 30G of memory, others might come along with a similar problem and they might benefit from allocating less.

Comment: In particular, you could remove the "-Xms" flag, and let the JVM size up to what it likes.

Comment: @pauldoo In case the -Xmx is realistic, I like to recommend -Xmx to be identical to -Xms: If you start with 2G, but the VM decides sunday night at 3am that it wants to allocate its full allowance from the OS but fails, you'll get an OOM despite properly setting the maximum. At least for production systems this is my default recommendation. For nonproduction I'd agree with you.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing for production systems also requires you add -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, otherwise lazy allocation by your OS can still cause a surprise when the JVM first tries to use a particular section of the heap.

Comment: Thanks, @pauldoo. I will definitely have a look and add this to the toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you need Incremental GC to reduce pauses:

- -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode

and for tracing without visualgc this always went well for me (output in catalina.out):

- -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps

> 2013-01-05T22:52:13.954+0100: 15918369.557: [GC 15918369.557: [DefNew:
>   65793K->227K(98304K), 0.0031220 secs] 235615K->170050K(491520K),
>   0.0033220 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

After you can play with this:

- -XX:NewSize=ABC -XX:MaxNewSize=ABC
- -XX:SurvivorRatio=ABC
- -XX:NewRatio=ABC

Reference: [Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)